Golang zerolog - Can Caller print wrapped handle functions' file and line number?
I am using generic Handle functions to wrap my specific HTTP Handlers to reuse error handling etc. Which makes me ultimately call my error printing in the same function, which causes the Caller output to always be this function and line. I'm hoping to print the line returning to this function, but I'm not sure that's available in the call stack. Is there any way to print the returning error line using this method? Should I switch to logging directly in the http handler?
handler.go
func (h *Handler) Handle(fn appHandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if e := fn(h.app, w, r); e != nil {
            if e.Context != nil {
                logger := e.Context.Caller().Logger(). // prints this file and line number
                logger.Error().Stack().Err(e.Error).Msg(e.LogMessage)
            } else {
                log.Error().Err(e.Error).Msg(e.LogMessage)
            }

            if e.HttpCode != 0 {
                http.Error(w, e.HttpMessage, e.HttpCode)
            } else {
                http.Error(w, e.HttpMessage, http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        }
    }
}

endpoints.go
func init() {
    router.Post("/user", handler.Handle(userHandler))
}

func userHandler(app *App, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *AppError {
    userUid := r.Context().Value(authentication.UserUid).(string)
    logger := log.With().Str("userUid", userUid)

    // do some processing logic
    user, err := database.FindUser(userUid)
    if err != nil {
        return &AppError{Error: err, Context: &logger} // want to print this file and line number
    }

    // more stuff

    return nil // success

}

